# Jquery ui autocomplete inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, runtime-error

I have added to my web application the jquery `ui plugin` in order to use `autocomplete widget`. The plugin is successfully working in one of my inputs; no errors are being thrown.

However, further in the code, while the user is interacting with a web form, I generate some `inputs[type=text]` dynamically. I want those inputs to use the plugin too and for that I created a function that is called after the inputs are created. This function uses the `.autocomplete()` function, but the browser throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

I don't get it since my first on-load created input is working fine and it's all in the same source file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This would suggest your jQuery UI library is not loading. We will need to see a more complete example. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the error via a smaller example, but I can´t. Is it possible that the function, somehow gets out of the scope of the library or something like that? My preloaded input is implementing the plugin without any problem.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Without seeing how things are being used, there is no way for us to know.

Comment: I think i got the solution. I was importing another js file that had a jquery declaration of a different version. Since I didn´t create that js file I didn't know its content. Thank you @Twisty